# What is a fallback for the "hamburger icon" or HTML entity &#9776;?

Tags: android, html, html-entities

I have this as my menu bar for the site when viewed on tablet:

[image: Header menu]

The menu icon on the right shows other options when clicked. The code is

```
<div id="menu">
  <a id="metaMenu" href="#">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

But I saw on Twitter that the entity (or it may have been the corresponding Unicode characters) is not supported in some Android phones. How can I modify my HTML to have a fallback?

Comment: Why you don't use a image?

Comment: Maybe even an = sign since that will render ever so lovely all the time.

Comment: @dymmeh: every image on the page is a server request and has a negative influence for performance - it's the reason why lots of people use a single sprite.png where stuff every icon used among the website

Comment: Using &#8801; instead worked for me, as answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070745/unicode-9776-hamburger-not-displaying-in-android-chrome

Answer (score 11):

i use `&equiv;` as of my knowledge this works most of the time.

Comment: I love this simplicity of this answer.  Being a mathematical operator I would be surprised If this is not supported universally.

Answer (score 8):

Image is a wrong way to go about this - as is an entity, in my opinion. As this one is not well supported at all. No Android, renders weird on Windows Chrome, Internet Explorer, etc.

Go the CSS3 route. This is supported by every major browser - and all modern mobile devices.

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/328k7/

***Use CSS3 as below. Edit where you see fit...***

```
div {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 14px;
    top: 0;
    height: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 10px 1px 1px #69737d,1px 16px 1px 1px     #69737d,1px 22px 1px 1px #69737d;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 0 1px #69737d,0 16px 0 1px #69737d,0 22px 0 1px #69737d;
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but [according to caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=box%20shadow), multiple shadows are not supported in safari and the android default browser, making this not the greatest solution for mobile

Comment: @Markasoftware way back when maybe...if you're running a really outdated Safari. Even mobile, unless you're using a brick - should work. I believe I took this code from Zurb Foundation framework.

Comment: Oh, nevermind. I read the tables incorrectly at caniuse. Sorry!

Answer (score 4):

The solution used by Twitter Bootstrap is using spans to construct the Hamburger:

```
<button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

The corresponding CSS is:

```
.navbar-toggle {
   position: relative;
   float: right;
   padding: 9px 10px;
   margin-top: 8px;
   margin-right: 15px;
   margin-bottom: 8px;
   background-color: #cccccc;
   border: 1px solid transparent;
   border-radius: 4px;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
   display: block;
   width: 22px;
   height: 2px;
   background-color:#000000;
   border-radius: 1px;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar+.icon-bar {
   margin-top: 4px;
}
```

Comment: As of BS4 you'll want to use a single `<span>` and the [`navbar-toggler-icon`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/#external-content) class, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I ended up doing it, with an inline SVG element defined in the CSS:

```
#menu_button {
    margin-top: 2vmin;
    margin-left: 2vmin;
    width: 8vmin;
    height: 8vmin;
    background-size: 100%;
    /* inline SVG element! */
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox="0 0 120 80" width="40" height="40" version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect x="15" width="90" height="15" rx="10"></rect><rect x="15" y="30" width="90" height="15" rx="10"></rect><rect x="15" y="60" width="90" height="15" rx="10"></rect></svg>');
}
```

Note that the string in url() must be all on one line -- no newline characters.  Then pop in your HTML:

```
<button id="menu_button" type="button" onclick="show_menu()">
</button>
```

With this method you can make a hamburger image styled *exactly* as you want it, but without having to load a separate image file from your server.