# Unicode &#9776; hamburger not displaying in Android & Chrome

Tags: android, html, unicode, font-face, hamburger-menu

I noticed that my hamburger menu icon has stopped displaying in Chrome for Android and also, in the Android browser now I simply get the missed icon image. It still works in all desktop browsers, in Safari and on Windows phone browsers.

I've created a test page to show the problem, included below. I'm confused about this as two months ago it was working fine when testing was completed and nothing has been changed or updated since.I wondered if anybody had any advice? Has something changed recently to cause this - do I need to look at alternative methods?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>    
p.sansserif {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p class="sansserif">This is the hamburger, &#9776; , there. </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You better provide your **png** graphics and use it as a **compound drawable** in your TextView.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've worked around this problem by using the UNICODE character UNICODE U+2261 (8801), ≡ IDENTICAL TO as illustrated below rather than the UNICODE U+2630 (9776) ☰ TRIGRAM FOR HEAVEN which seems to have font support issues on my Android devices.

```
<p class="sansserif">&#8801; Menu </p>
```

I preferred not to do it with an image for simplicity and resizing.

Comment: `Trigram for heaven` is actually a Chinese character hence the lack of it on Android: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagua#Trigrams