# Where do I get a "3 horizontal lines" symbol for my webpage?

Tags: html, css, hamburger-menu

I'm trying to figure out how to get this symbol on my webpage:

[image: symbol]

What is the symbol called? Is there a way to get it on my webpage like there is to get the ▾ by using

```
&#9662;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That symbol is commonly referred as "hamburger button". There are quite a few ways to do it, as described in here: https://css-tricks.com/three-line-menu-navicon/

Comment: Animated ones http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedMenuIcon/, https://codepen.io/kyleHenwood/pen/Alayb, http://codepen.io/designcouch/pen/Atyop, http://callmenick.com/_development/css-hamburger-menu-icons/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the ways provided in the [link in comment](https://css-tricks.com/three-line-menu-navicon/) are great. but there is also a way not described there, the same as bootstrap is using too. The preference of this method is because it is pure CSS animatable.

```
<div class="menu-icon">
    <span class="line"></span>
    <span class="line"></span>
    <span class="line"></span>
</div>

.menu-icon > .line {
    background-color: #292929;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
}
.menu-icon > .line + .line {
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/znec584x/ small edit from Farzad's for those that come in the future. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 14):

This is a so-called "hamburger menu".

The closest HTML entity you can get is ≡, bold **≡** `&#8801;` or `&equiv;`, [supported almost everywhere](http://unicode.johnholtripley.co.uk/2261/).

There is also ☰ `&#9776;`, but it is [less supported](http://unicode.johnholtripley.co.uk/2630/), in particular it is [not available on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070745/unicode-9776-hamburger-not-displaying-in-android-chrome).

It can be enough for a small icon, and if you need a bigger one, here is a pure CSS implementation:

```css
.ham-menu { display: inline-block; position: relative; margin: 35px 0; } /* margin = (width-height)/2 */
.ham-menu, .ham-menu::before, .ham-menu::after { width: 100px; height: 20px; border-radius: 7px; background-color: black; }
.ham-menu::before, .ham-menu::after { content: ""; display: block; position: absolute; }
.ham-menu::before { bottom: 130%; } .ham-menu::after { top: 130%; }
```

```html
<span class="ham-menu"></span>
```

Comment: And to display it in a pseudo `:before` or `:after` element, for example `.menu:before { content: "\2261";}` which comes from the hex value found [here](https://www.codetable.net/decimal/8801).

Answer (score 5):

You can find the unicode & html entity codes here: https://graphemica.com/%E2%98%B0

Or just copy & paste this simple symbol: ☰

Answer (score -2):

you can use font awesome

```
<button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
```

the css part

```
.btn {
    border: none;
    background-color: ghostwhite;
    color: black;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

to either expand on click  you might need some javascript select using classes

```
const closeBtn = document.querySelector(".btn");
const sidenav = document.querySelector(".sidenav");
const closeSideNav = document.querySelector(".closeSideNav");

closeBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    sidenav.classList.remove("hidden");
});
```