# What is the alternative for ['&#9776;'] for mobile phones?

Tags: unicode, icons

I'm using `☰` (unicode `&#9776;)` to be shown as a burger icon for mobile phones, but unfortunately it doesn't appear on mobile phones. Why is that?

Is there is another way to show it on mobile phones?

Comment: Are you talking in an app like phoneGap -- Or straight web browser?  Which browsers if so??

Comment: Either the mobile browser's font doesn't have that character, or you made a mistake.

Comment: ☰ Works in iOS 11

Comment: If it's mobile web -- I'd use a third party font like **fontawesome** -- http://fontawesome.io/ or **Glyphicons** http://glyphicons.com/  to prevent incompatibility

Comment: @Zak , web browser 'uc browser'

Comment: @JJJ , It shows when I decrease the size of the browser width on PC , How to make the font to have the character?

Comment: You can't. Use another font.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a fallback for the "hamburger icon" or HTML entity &#9776;?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282760/what-is-a-fallback-for-the-hamburger-icon-or-html-entity-9776)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using either [fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/) or [material.io](https://material.io/icons/). You cant rely on devices universally supporting a particular emoji. They can differ greatly between different devices, and OS Versions.